# Inject a service without referencing the concrete service name

Tags: angularjs

I have a localStorageService whose implementation must be generic, that means it must not be bound to a certain service like 'customerServicer' or 'productService'

The localStorageService should accept a service/get injected a service which is not the literal string name of the service.

How can I do that without having types/interfaces in angularjs... ???

```
'use strict';
angular.module('myapp').service('localStorageService', function (localStorageService, customerService) {

    // impl generic caching functions which works for all CRUD services
});
```

Comment: Sorry confused by "concrete service name". Are you asking how to inject a service into another service?

Comment: @Dom A service is automatically injected when you write the service name in the function parameters. But I do not want to bind myself to the service name. I want to write a generic working caching service used for ALL my services. Thus I can not write the literal service name in the injection params.

Comment: Your question seems not be clear. Are you want a generic service which accepts another service name & returns its instance?

Comment: You mean you want your service to be autoloaded in all other services?

Comment: @ShashankAgrawal I want a generic service which accepts another service. But the injected service name can not be used because the generic service can not be bound to a concrete service name to work generically.

Comment: In your example, how will localStorageService, customerService and productService interact, and which do you see getting injected into your controllers and how will that be used by your controller?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this:

```
myAppModule.factory('genericService', ['$injector', function(injector) {
    return {
        get: function(serviceName) {
            return $injector.get(serviceName);
        }
    };
}]);
```

Now in another location like in controller:

```
myAppModule.controller('TestController', function($scope, genericService) {
    // Use the generic service to get another service instance
    var appService = genericService.get('appService');
});
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a factory with a generic service name that returns an actual implementation.

```
factory('localStorage', ['myLocalStorage', function(myLocalStorage) { return myLocalStorage} ])
```

So if you want to swap out the implementation of myLocalStorage with something else, you only need to do it in this one place.

About types and interfaces. Typescript give you these.

So for example, you can define an interface, ITokenStorage,  of how you want to store a token. Then you can pass in $sessionStorage, $localStorage or $cookieStorage as a type implementing that interface to easily change how you want to store the token.

This is all doable with Angular 1.x. TypeScript is opensource and installs with Npm. IDEs and editors support it.

Comment: No no no ;-) I do not want to make the localStorageService with multiple implementations - that would defeat the purpose of a generic class  I want to make the localStorageService work with a generic service name so every service can be injected!

Comment: @Elisa, what is an example of a generic service name? The example I gave allows you to inject a service of one name under another name? Is that different from what you want?

Comment: @Martin i think so you are right. Generic can be anything but you always need to know what you want to implement.

Comment: @elisa, I don't use the patter myself of using a factory to return another service, but I do use the pattern of having a generic Typescript interface that any storage service can implement.

Comment: @Martin I do not use TypeScript nor do I plan learning it :-)